# How to get post values by Body-parser - Express Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, body-parser

I am using 
Express 4.11.1, and 
Body-parser 1.11.0.
When I run the following code I am getting following output

Please suggest how to get the form value

**Output**

```
{}
```

**server.js**

```
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

var app = express();
var router = express.Router();

app.use(bodyParser.json(),bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
// Routes

app.get('/', function(req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index1.html');
});

app.post('/', function(req, res){    
    console.log(req.body);
    res.send(req.body);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index1.html');
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("Working on port 3000");
});
```

**index1.html**

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
<form id="frmTest" name="frmTest" action="http://localhost:3000/" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="mytext" value="sadfsad fsd fsad" />
  <input type="submit" id="mysubmit" />
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I could be wrong, but I think you'll have to call `app.use` twice, and that it doesn't accept a comma separated list

Answer (score 1):

To retrieve data on backend side you must just add name to input field

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
  <body>
<form id="frmTest" name="frmTest" action="http://localhost:3000/" method="post">
  <input type="text" id="mytext" name="mytext" value="sadfsad fsd fsad" />
  <input type="submit" id="mysubmit" />
</form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
app.post('/', function(req, res){    
    console.log(req.body.**NAMEATTRIBUTE**);
    res.send(req.body);
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/index1.html');
});
```

Give your html 'name' attribute.